# Pivot Viewer V2 doesn't release memory after being set to null

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, garbage-collection, pivotviewer

In our LOB app, We have 4 pivot viewers on separate pages in a navigation control. When we navigate from one pivot viewer to another the memory increases (as expected).

This memory continues to increase however to a point where the system runs out of memory. We have added in cases to dereference everything (events / itemsource/ properties /templates) when the page is navigated away from and explicitly call the GC.Collect method for testing

I've create a MS Connect issue for it at 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/787032/pivot-viewer-v2-doesnt-release-memory-after-being-set-to-null

which has a sample app up on it that reproduces it

Steps to Repro are
Navigate to the Patients page
Navigate back to Locations page

Just keep navigating between the two pages. Memory is never fully reclaimed (I also have a page that will just call the GC which doesn't reclaim the memory)

Any help in sorting this out or even pushing me in the right direction to solve it would be great or ideas for a work around

Thanks

Comment: I can't look at the app until I get home. But are you sure it's the `PivotViewer` and not some other object you're not `Dispose()`ing?

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I'm pretty sure its the viewer thats not getting disposed as I've dereferenced everything I can think of ..events/item source/itemtemplates/pivot properties etc